# Over what parts of current Israel do the laws of Shemittah apply?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, geography, shmita, state-of-israel

Over what parts of current Israel do the laws of Shemittah apply?
Do the laws apply to the West Bank (Judea and Samaria)?

Comment: I don't see why the political borders affect anything. I would argue that much of the Negev does not fall into Shemittah Israel, while the Territories, southern Lebanon, and parts of Jordan do. My source is the likely-innacurate map in the Artscroll Chumash and Tana"ch.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure about 'Azza and the neighbouring Israeli coastline, which was historically Philistia.

Comment: While J&S are definitely halachically part of Eretz Yisrael, a better question would be the Golan Heights.

Comment: Please supply sources for your two statements.

Comment: A full answer to this question would actually be very complicated... see the Mishnah in Sheviis chapter 6 and commentaries there; this question usually occupies a chapter or more in contemporary books on the laws of shmitah (maybe later I'll post a summary). Regarding the West Bank, though, you won't find a source that says explicitly that the laws apply, because the laws of shemittah don't recognize any differences based on current political bounderies. It would be like asking, "what's the source that the mitzvah of tzitzis applies on Wednesdays"

Comment: @Matt Thank you. I look forward to your summary and could you please recommend a contemporary book on the laws of shmitah (which contains the section I need). I understand the point about political boundaries; however we know geographically what is meant by "the West Bank" and so from the geographical references, we can work out he answer.

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt: While I cannot cite sources, from my personal experience the agricultural towns in the Arava Desert (south of the Negev proper) greatly enjoyed being able to sell local produce without restriction during Shemittah years.

Comment: @arp, that's also true.

Answer (score 2):

Judea and Samaria most certainly falls into halachic E.Y. borders. In fact, during the first two temples, that was the center of Jewish life. There may be questions regarding Azza, south of Negev (including Eilat), and the Golan.

Comment: Please supply sources for your two statements.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Check a map of ancient Eretz Yisrael.